# C# / RegEx - How can I improve my RegEx expression?

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I have an question about my code with RegEx. My case is that I have about 700 text files, which I import within my tool and that is sometime taking under one second or sometimes taking up to 7 seconds.

So I profiled my tool and it was saying `File.ReadAllLines`and my RegEx is taking the most time.. So maybe some RegEx pro can help me and teach me how I can improve my RegEx expression.

This is my code:

```
var entries = new List<SomeModelObject>();

            try
            {
                var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath, Encoding.Default);

                var isHashCollected = false;
                // main pattern
                var pattern = @"[a-zA-Z<>:_]+\s+SYMBOL:\s(?<var>\w+)(|\s+)=\s(?<value>\W\w+|\w+)\s;\s\/\/(?<comment>.*)";
                Match match;
                Regex regex = new Regex(pattern,
                      RegexOptions.Singleline);

                var secondPattern = @"<0:64:0>[\w\s;]+\/\/\s(?<second>\w+)";
                Regex regexSecondPattern  = new Regex(secondPattern , RegexOptions.Singleline);

                var thirdPattern = @"<@\(#\)(?<third>\w+)";
                Regex regexThirdPattern  = new Regex(thirdPattern , RegexOptions.Singleline);
                

                foreach (var line in allLines)
                {
                    if (!isHashCollected)
                    {
                        isHashCollected = GetHash(regexThirdPattern.Match(line), someObject, isHashCollected);
                    }

                    match = regex.Match(line);

                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        // get entries
                        var someModelObject= new SomeModelObject();
                        someModelObject.projCase = match.Groups["var"].Value;
                        someModelObject.projValue = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                        someModelObject.projComment = match.Groups["comment"].Value;
                        entries.Add(someModelObject);
                        continue;
                    }

                    GetSecondHash(regexSecondPattern.Match(line), someObject);

                }

                return entries;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new List<SomeModelObject>();
            }
```

For completness:

```
private static bool GetHash(Match match, SomeObject someObject, bool isHashCollected)
    {
        if (match.Success)
        {
            someObject.hash = match.Groups["third"].Value;
            return true; 
        }
        return isHashCollected;
    }

    private static void GetSecondHash(Match match, SomeObject someObject)
    {
        if (match.Success)
        {
            someObject.hash = match.Groups["second"].Value;
        }
    }
```

So I got three expressions, but I think "main pattern" must be improved. Maybe there is some other culprint here and I dont see it (any help is appreciated!)

And those are some lines from **one** file (where I do my RegEx) each has the same format:

```
<@(#)123456788c81a76adc83466212345678 
// 
<ABC_Defg:Element>  SYMBOL: ABCDEF = 00001  ;   //Some text
<ABC_Defg:Value>    SYMBOL: ABCDEF = 00000  ;   //Some text
<ABC_Defg:Value>    SYMBOL: ABCDEF = 00000  ;   //Some text


<0:64:0> 0xABCDEF 0xABCDEF 0xABCDEF0 0xABCDEF ; // 12345678f0aa885f12345678
```

As I said any help is appreciated!!! Thanks

**UPDATE**

I updated my pattern to this `(?<var>[^:]*)[=](?<value>[^=]*)[;](?<comment>[^;]*)` and I also parallized the reading of files with `Parallel.ForeEach` (thanks @charlieface) so I have now ~1 second to read and display input of 700 files. Thanks buddys for helping me out!

Comment: It's unclear what `GetHash` does. How much improvement do you get by compiling the Regex? `.Compile()`

Comment: I have updated it, but there isnt any wild calclulation or so just adding to model...

Comment: OK and have you tried compiling the Regex objects?

Comment: Is it sufficient just to add RegexOption.Compiled? Like `new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);`

Comment: Yes that should be fine

Comment: Just RegEx option doesnt change a bit, but will try with `.Compile()`

Comment: Seems like you could improve the logic: are these regexes mutually exclusive? Is the second and third only for the first line of the file, perhaps you can skip checking on the rest of the lines. How many lines in these files anyway?

Comment: Those files vary from size, but I think 50 to 70 lines are the average. Third pattern is on line 3 but is represented through boolean, so it will only be processed if `isHashCollected == false` and second pattern is penultimate line, but will only be processed if main pattern is not successful. So what would you improve?

Comment: Then shouldn't the `if (!isHashCollected)` block have a `continue;`?

Comment: I could add that, but I dont think that this will impact a lot, cause in the processing of a file in the first 3 lines `isHashCollected` will be set to true. I thought that my regex pattern could be maybe more efficient, but I am not a pro to evaluate my pattern.

Comment: So I changed my pattern and I am now at constant ~3.50 seconds, but I really dont understand why sometimes my old approach was ready within 1 second...

Comment: What about just parallelizing it over the file list

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the hint, I did indeed not parallelizing it *facepalm and I am now at ~1 second! I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why are you doing `var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(...); ... foreach (var line in allLines) { ...}`? Why not read it line by line and use `string line; while((line = File.ReadLine()) != null) {  ... }`?

Comment: ^ You probably want `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(...))` (or use a `StreamReader`): the code above won't compile

Comment: @canton7 I have update my code above, but this is specific company code, therefore you have to live with `SomeModelObject` and `SomeObject` - Maybe both appoaches from @canton7 and @AdreanHHH are also efficent, but I do not see any speed improvements after `while((line = File.ReadLine()) != null) {  ... }` with use of `StreamReader` I am still at 1 second which is totally fine!!

Answer (score 2):

When the data has specific patterns, change any positive search to be a negative search. So take you the pattern of a *non word then any words* or `|` *just words* to have it consume everything up to the `;`.

```
 (?<value>\W\w+|\w+)
```

and change it to consume *anything that is not* a `;`

```
(?<value>[^;]+)
```

which will do the same thing but not have the parser doing extra work because of the `|` you have. Because everything then ends at the `\s;` which I would remove and have `;` only.  At minimum have it be `\W?\w+` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already updated my pattern to --> `(?<var>[^:]*)[=](?<value>[^=]*)[;](?<comment>[^;]*)`

Comment: Usage of the `*` can lead to, too much unnecessary backtracking. If you **Know** there is data, use `+` instead to avoid all backtracking.